Не воспринимается один из аргументов в функции
код :
pars1 = {'1': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/1.html','2': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/2.html', '3': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/3.html', '4': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/4.html', '5': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/5.html',
         '6': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/6.html', '7': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/7.html', '8': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/8.html', '9': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/9.html', '10': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/10.html',
         '11': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/11.html', '12': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/12.html', '13': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/13.html', '14': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/14.html', '15': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/15.html',
         '16': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/16.html', '17': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/17.html', '18': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/18.html', '19': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/19.html', '20': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/20.html',
         '21': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/21.html', '22': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/22.html', '23': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/23.html', '24': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/24.html', '25': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/25.html',
         '26': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/26.html', '27': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/27.html', '28': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/28.html', '29': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/29.html', '30': 'https://tepka.ru/himiya_8/30.html'}

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bn(message, pars1):
    b = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, b)
    for i in pars1():
        if b in pars1.keys():
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, pars1[b])

ошибка :
TypeError: bn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pars1'


Так уберите просто этот аргумент из сигнатуры хандлера def bn(message, pars1): -> def bn(message): Эта переменная и так вам будет доступна внутри функции. А откуда она возьмётся при вызове хандлера, с чего её вам телеграм вдруг передаст параметром - непонятно.

Вы осознаете, что pars1 в строчке def bn(message, pars1) и переменаая pars1,  которая выше, вообще никак не связаны?

все наоборот - аргумент воспринимается, только вы его не передаете. и, судя по коду, не должны бы передавать.

Кстати да, как ещё в удалённом ответе написали, строка for i in pars1(): вообще ни к селу ни к городу. Но это уже после того, как основную ошибку почините.
